# https certificates for 2 IP addresses on the same server

Tags: networking, ssl, https, nginx, ssl-certificate

We are working on a router-like device which can have it’s own access point and be connected to another router. We want to have `https` on the management web page using a valid certificate (not a self-signed one) for it but we have found a big problem.

As a certificate is for a host name (or IP), we can use a certificate for the internal network (we control the DNS server) but if somebody access the web from the external network we will have a problem since the hostname and IP address doesn’t match.

Is there any way to solve the problem 1 serversL: 2 IP addresses with 1 certficate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SAN certificate which lets you have multiple domains in one certificate.  There are multiple providers that offer this, though it tends to be more expensive.  That way you can have one domain which you use internally which resolves to the internal IP and one you use externally which resolves to the public IP.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubjectAltName

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a variety of ways.

1. List all possible IPs/hostnames referring to the router in the certificate.
2. List only a hostname in the certificate, and ensure that internal/external DNS will resolve to the proper IP.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know a certificate could apply to multiple hostnames without a wildcard or similar. I'm going to try it and resolve the question. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your internal network has local IP addresses.

According the link below, local IPs cannot be used for certificates.

https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1216536-securing-a-public-ip-address---ssl-certificates

If you use 2 real IP addresses, you could try SAN certificate

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubjectAltName